# react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure you're running your app on the native platform

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I have this error when I'm building my react native App:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2tOg.png)

I have the dependency and the pods installed, this is my package.json:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Odi.png)

I'm on Mac Intel chip.

(This error is showed on iOS Emulator and Android Emulator) I don't know if this error is showed on mobile

Try installing dependencies, installing pods, clearing cache, deleting the app and rebuilding

Comment: Did you run ```npx pod-install``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
```

or

```
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
```

more details at [Docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/next/installation/)